# Get iframe attributes inside iframe javascript with cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How to get iframe attributes inside iframe javascript code

```
<div>
<iframe src="http://192.168.0.108:8092/"
            name="otherDomain"
            width="100%"
            height="600px"
            style="border: 0;"
            data-auth-token="xyz"
            data-auth-key="abc"
      >
</div>
```

I am trying with

```
console.log(window.frameElement.getAttribute('data-auth-token'))
```

If iframe url and browser user is same I am able to get iframe attributes. if the urls are different I am getting following error.

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'frame' property from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "http://192.168.0.108:8092" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:8092". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

Is it possible to get cross domain iframe attributes inside JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, it isn't possible to work with iframes that refer to another domain. The browser automatically blocks all the scripts that try to access the frame from another domain. If something like this was possible, then it would have been a huge security flaw.

In your case, you can set the `iframe` attribute `src` to `localhost:8092`, so you'll have an `iframe` with the same location (and the same domain name), and you'll be able to access its data.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation  @Marco Bonelli. I thinking wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access attributes from inside an iframe, but you can access the query string.

For example:

In parent html: `<iframe src="/x?a=1"></iframe>`

In iframe JavaScript: `window.location.search`